# CSS - Why grid frameworks does not provide top or bottom margin or padding classes?

Tags: css

Question may be very basic.

Been worked on Bootstrap and Blueprint etc.. 
We have classes for specifying width : span1 to span12... etc
classes for left and right : append1 to append-48 and prepend-1 to prepend-48 etc..

1. Is there any reason why we have no classes for specifying top or bottom margin and top or bottom padding?
2. What would be the better way to do handle this scenario? using br tag or by using css itself?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Width is critical to any grid. Height, on the other hand, is normally fluid and at the discretion of the content creator or developer. Either use CSS selectors to add your margins, or add additional classes to those elements on which you want to add margin or padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not familiar with Bootstrap or Blueprint so cant answer why no classes exist for specifying margin/padding.
However using br for spacing is not a good idea. A better idea if you want to add padding or margins to your span tags, is to use a css selector. For example:

```
span{margin:10px 20px;padding:10px 20px;}
```

or for individual span tags

```
.span1, .span5, .span12{margin:0 20px;}
```

etc...

Comment: Be careful with span. By default they have "display: inline", adding margin and padding will not work as expected. EX: http://jsfiddle.net/2TERe/2/

Comment: {display: inline-block} is a better idea. {display: block} will destroy most grids.